# Why do people remember things when they stop trying to remember?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, language

I posted this question on SE English:

[Antonym for ameliorate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127185/antonym-for-ameliorate)

I had been trying to recall a word and it's recollection kept evading me.

I remembered the word as soon as I posted the question; which was when I gave up trying to recall it.

What is the scientific term and process by where a person cannot recall something and then remembers it when they stop trying?